# How to designate controller dependencies when passing function to controller property of state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am registering a controller on the state object by giving it a function. However the controller depends on things like $scope,$rootScope, and a couple of other services. How can I make the notation work if I am passing it a function? The solution should also work if the code is minified.

Here is my code

```
var mod = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);

mod.config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider',function(u,$stateP){

     $stateP.state('myState',{

        controller : controllerFunction //this is the controller that has dependencies.
     })

}]);
```

As a side note -- I know there exist a `resolve` property that can be used to pass dependencies, but how can I pass $scope when it isn't defined, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the documentation states otherwise (look at the [controller property](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)) the controller property will happily take an inline array of dependencies with the controller function being the last index like so.

```
{
   controller : ['$scope','$http',...,controllerFunction];
}
```